# Experiencing high latency in GCP Redis memory store

Tags: google-cloud-platform, redis, google-cloud-run, node-redis

while getting the data from Redis in the cloud run. I notice a high latency in it. it takes around 4 mins to get the data from Redis. how many concurrent calls can GCP Redis handle? do I need to change any configuration in Redis? Also noted in CPU seconds metrics, it reaches 1. Is it normal? it reaches only 1k calls per second. we started experiencing latency. is there any solution to resolve this?

Redis version - 4.0

memory - 5 GB

capacity - 5 GB

replica - 1

tier - standard

read replica - na

Answer (score 0):

> how many concurrent calls can GCP Redis handle?

Based on this documentation on [Memorystore for Redis Instance limits](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/quotas#instance_limits) it can handle up to **65,000** concurrent connections across all tiers (Basic, Standard, and Standard with read replicas).

> do I need to change any configuration in Redis?

You can change the following configuration for your Redis instance:

- Display name
- Redis configuration
- Labels
- Size (For more information on scaling, see [Scaling Instances](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/scaling-instances).)

> Also noted in CPU seconds metrics, it reaches 1. Is it normal?

This is normal as the threshold trigger for CPU utilization is set to **1**. You can check this documentation on [setting an alert for high Redis engine CPU utilization](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/monitor-instances#set_an_alert_for_high_redis_engine_cpu_utilization).

> it reaches only 1k calls per second. we started experiencing latency. is there any solution to resolve this?

API request quota by default is set to **5,000** per **100 seconds**. This includes the following operations:

- Get operations (`gcloud redis instances describe`)
- List operations (`gcloud redis instances list`)
- Create operations
- Import/export operations
- Update operations

You cannot request for a quota increase however you can follow the [Exponential backoff recommendations](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/exponential-backoff) to reduce the number of API requests made if an error is encountered. You can refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/quotas#per-second_api_requests_quota) for more information.

Comment: # Connection with master lost.
* Caching the disconnected master state.
# Connection with slave client lost.

We are getting this logs in redis. we figured out that, latency was because the master connection was lost. it took few minutes to promote the slave to the master. in the logs, i am not able to get the reason why the master connection was lost. is there any way to figure why master connection was lost